# Nuget-update won't install because of access denied error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, nuget, updates, access-violation

I'm using VS2012 under Windows7 64 bit. Now there is an update for the Nuget package manager within Visual Studio that I can't install, neither from the update mechanism within VS itself, nor when I download the latest Nuget version as a VSIX and try to install it manually.

The error message is localized, but in basically says something like:

```
Access denied; HRESULT 0x80070005 (E_ACCESDENIED)
```

There's also a link to more specific details in that message box that gives the following information (here are only the last lines where the error occurs):

```
05.05.2014 07:22:27 - Failed to initialize settings for Isolated Shell c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe: Zugriff verweigert (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
05.05.2014 07:22:27 - Installiertes Produkt gefunden - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional
05.05.2014 07:22:27 - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Zugriff verweigert (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   bei System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.GetScopePaths(String applicationPath, String suffixOrName, String vsVersion, Boolean isLogged, Boolean isForIsolatedApplication)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(String applicationPath)
   bei VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManager(SupportedVSSKU sku)
   bei VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManagerForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1 applicableSKUs)
   bei VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

As far as I can see, there's a problem with accessing the SQL Server Management Studio executable (`ssms.exe`). The VSIX installation runs with admin privileges, so I wonder that there is an access problem at all. So I tried to explicitely set file and folder permissions to full rights for everyone, but the error remains.

I'm really surprised this error occurs because in my eyes I don't have a highly customized environment but a rather standard one... don't they test their updates properly before rolling them out?

Any help on resolving this issue is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you solve this problem? How?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the way `My documents` is mapped. In my company `My Documents` (aka `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`) was mapped to a network share. So, I had the same issue when I was not able to access `My documents` any more.

Changing the registry to a local folder or fixing your issue with accessing `My documents` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.